# Driving from Berlin to Auschwitz-Birkenau

Tags: road-trips, poland, berlin, tolls, auschwitz

My boyfriend and I will be travelling from Berlin to Auschwitz-Birkenau, Poland in October. I have been trying my hardest to figure out the cost of the toll roads, but as I don't have a great understanding of how their toll roads work, I'm having trouble figuring it out. We will be entering onto A4 at the interchange Krzyżowa and will be exiting at what I'm assuming is Jeleń. We will be travelling in a 4-door car. 
Just wondering if anyone has any information on the tolls roads and approximate cost as I know it's per kilometre. 
Thank you!

Comment: I can't really write a full post right now, but this should help http://www.tolls.eu/poland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reply by @martin is almost right, except that you don't have to pay for A4 on the 2nd paid section, toll booths are located after you pass Myslowice (exit Brzęczkowice) and when going towards Krakow, but you don't want to do it as you take right turn there and via S1 (shortly) you go to Oswiecim through Imielin

to sum up, you enter Poland near Cottbus (A18) or near Goerlitz (A4), until Wroclaw it's free of charge, then after passing Wroclaw, you have to pay 16,2 PLN (~4 EUR) to reach Gliwice, then you have another free section until Myslowice, where you exit highway

note: DO NOT miss the exit, because right after it, there are toll booths and you have to pay 10 PLN even if you exit 5km farther, this is the route you should take to avoid payment:

https://www.google.pl/maps/dir/50.2594178,18.7114729/Miejsce+Pami%C4%99ci+i+Muzeum+Auschwitz-Birkenau,+Wi%C4%99%C5%BAni%C3%B3w+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cimia+20,+32-603+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cim/@50.1881294,18.9054478,11.29z/data=!4m10!4m9!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716be32014dffa1:0xe8e173d6821a53c5!2m2!1d19.2019829!2d50.0274106!3e0!5i1?hl=pl

Comment: Thank you so much. This was actually very helpful I appreciate it! :)

Comment: you're welcome; one more hint - when going TO Poland, it might be a good idea to take the longer route via Goerlitz because A18 is a terrible, 80km long bumpy road good for tanks :) this is only the case on way FROM Germany, the lane towards Berlin is already rebulit

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the A4 there are two toll sections: [Bielany Wrocławskie (PPO Karwiany) to Sośnica (PPO Żernica)](http://www.viatoll.pl/en/cars-manual-toll/payments-and-toll-rates/toll-rates) and [Murckowska to Balice](https://www.autostrada-a4.com.pl/oplaty/kalkulator_oplat).

You'll cover the first segment in its entirety paying 16,20 zł <s>and then another 10 zł from Murckowska to Jelen, which totals around 6 € or 7.25 $.</s> which is around 3,80 € or 4.50 $. If you [take the exit at Myslowice](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Myslowice,+Poland/Memorial+and+Museum+Auschwitz-Birkenau,+Wi%C4%99%C5%BAni%C3%B3w+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cimia,+Oswiecim,+Poland/@50.1230822,19.0953396,11z/data=!4m25!4m24!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m10!1m1!1s0x4716c45eb25a2a0d:0x5b32f6a8cbb58ed!2m2!1d19.1660513!2d50.2080466!3m4!1m2!1d19.1954966!2d50.1369825!3s0x4716c10c2a8785fd:0xc495d96bc384c650!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716be32014dffa1:0xe8e173d6821a53c5!2m2!1d19.2019829!2d50.0274106!3e0?hl=en) (versus Jelen which is the [default suggestion on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Memorial+and+Museum+Auschwitz-Birkenau,+Wi%C4%99%C5%BAni%C3%B3w+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cimia,+Oswiecim,+Poland/@51.2540996,14.2845583,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716be32014dffa1:0xe8e173d6821a53c5!2m2!1d19.2019829!2d50.0274106!3e0?hl=en)) you don't pay for the second segment. Distance and travel time are basically the same (within a couple of minutes).

If you want to avoid the tolls altogether [this](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Memorial+and+Museum+Auschwitz-Birkenau,+Wi%C4%99%C5%BAni%C3%B3w+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cimia,+Oswiecim,+Poland/@51.2540996,14.0740727,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m16!4m15!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716be32014dffa1:0xe8e173d6821a53c5!2m2!1d19.2019829!2d50.0274106!2m1!2b1!3e0?hl=en) should be the route, setting you back an additional 1 1/2 hours according to Google Maps.

Comment: not exactly, you take the exit in Myslowice right before toll booths, so you don't have to pay the second part of A4

Comment: Yes, that works too!