# Berlin to Auschwitz by car

Tags: germany, driving, poland, berlin, auschwitz

I want to drive from Berlin to Auschwitz in March of this year, but I read so many different mixed opinions. How long does it really take by car and how are the roads on this route? Is there a particular route that is better than the next? Thanks for any feedback provided.

Comment: You have to inform you car rental company you want to drive the car to Poland, because they charge you extra for that (higher insurance fees.) They may also limit the type of car you can use for your journey to cheaper ones which are unlikely to be stolen. It may be cheaper, also simpler and more comfortable, to take the train.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102267/driving-from-berlin-to-auschwitz-birkenau

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driving from Berlin to Auschwitz-Birkenau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102267/driving-from-berlin-to-auschwitz-birkenau)

Comment: There's also a (former) concentration camp  (Sachsenhausen) in Oranienburg, which is to the north-west of Berlin. This was used as the model for other concentration camps. It's on Scäferweg, about a 30 min walk from Oranienburg train station, which is 30 mins on the RE5 from Berlin Hbf. If you visit, then you should allow at lest 3 hours to see the exhibits.
The website for the museum is http://www.stiftung-bg.de/gums/en/index.htm

Comment: Note that the "duplicate" question that has been flagged only deals with the tolls;  this question is primarily concerned with travel time and road quality.

Comment: What have you tried? Nowadays we have numerous navigation services like Google Maps, do you have any reason not to trust them?

Comment: @DanubianSailor: Well, the OP asks about travel time, for which the estimates given by Google Maps are rather unreliable here in Germany in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to road conditions, at least the portion in Germany (which is about 1/3 of the way) you can expect a well paved motorway, so road conditions won't be a problem IMHO. I cannot speak for the Polish part of the way, though as I have never driven there. But also Poland is not a 3rd world country.

In Germany a rule of thumb is that you can usually expect to make about 100 km in one hour as long as there will be no traffic jams. It will be hard to predict if you will encounter any traffic jams on that route. But I'd plan some 6-8 hours one way.

Answer (score 1):

So, having been in this part of Poland as recently as last year, and regularly traveling in Germany I feel confident recommending you utilize Google Maps and their Offline Download feature.

Whether it is more favorable to drive or take the train is really about how much of a walker you are vs. how much of a gearhead you are. :) Personally, the first time I got to drive in Germany, !! I didn't stop. Seriously, it was our honeymoon and Hubs was stuck in the passenger seat.

Also, the dual country rental should not be an issue. An option to select and a small fee probably is all.

Google is saying that it should take almost 6 hours if you take the A4 (A4 is a Toll Rd), closer to 7 or 7.5 if you go the A2. All dependent on traffic of course.

You could always make a weekend of it and stop in Wroclaw on the way down, then after go another half hour to Krakow...

Some Logistics: The city Auschwitz is in is called Oswiecim, Poland

Here's the Museum address: Więźniów Oświęcimia 20, 32-603 Oświęcim, Poland

Directions:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Memorial+and+Museum+Auschwitz-Birkenau,+Wi%C4%99%C5%BAni%C3%B3w+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cimia+20,+32-603+O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cim,+Poland/@51.2528923,13.479186,7z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716be32014dffa1:0xe8e173d6821a53c5!2m2!1d19.2019829!2d50.0274106!3e0